# Implementing nested fetch API calls with setInterval for dashboard: fetch()+React+Typesctipt

Tags: reactjs, promise, fetch, setstate, react-table

I am trying to bring up a dashboard page with a react table. I want table to be refreshed every 2 seconds.Also I have two fetch api calls , where result of the first one is passed as a parameter to the second. Also second fetch call must set the chart data every two seconds.

Also if there are multiple tables that follows the same implementation of such fetch calls, how can I do it?

What is the better way to do it?

Help would be appreciated

```
 import * as React from 'react';
 import ReactTable from 'react-table';
 import 'react-table/react-table.css';

 interface IState {
    data: any[];
 }

 export default class Dashboard extends React.Component<{},IState> {

   constructor(props: any) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       data: [],
   }

   componentDidMount()
   { 
       const url="/api/query/fetch";    

        var result = fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            body : JSON.stringify({"id":"abc"),
            headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
           }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();

       }).then(function(data) {

        return fetch('api/query/fetch' + data.id); // want this call to be under setInterval such that chart data refreshes every 2 seconds, s uch that table data refreshes every 2 seconds
      })
      .then(function(response) {
           return response.json();
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Request failed', error)
      })
    result.then(function(r) {
         this.setState({data:r});
    });
  }     

  render(){
     return(
        <ReactTable 
           data={this.state.data} 
           columns={columns} //column config object
         />
     )   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import 'react-table/react-table.css';

interface IState {
    data: any[];
    id: any;
}

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component<{}, IState> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            id: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = "/api/query/fetch";

        fetch(
            url, 
            {
                method: 'post',
                body: JSON.stringify({ "id": "abc"}),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        ).then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (data) {
            this.setState({
                id: data.id
            }, () => this.fetchData())
        });
    }

    fetchData() {
        fetch('api/query/fetch' + this.state.id)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (r) {
            this.setState({ data: r });
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.fetchData();
            }, 2000);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Request failed', error)
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <ReactTable
                data={this.state.data}
                columns={columns} //column config object
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I want only the second call to be under setInterval. Thanks again

Comment: you don't need interval, once the data is fetched, the timeout will call feching again, after 2000ms, will enter a loop

Comment: @ Barbu Barbu , Also If I have I have multiple tables that follows the same fetch call sequence, how can I achieve all of it? Like in this ,how can I make all the tables to be refreshed every 2 seconds?

Comment: @velsonjr create an HOC that will take a url (the url to be used to fetch the data) as prop and then do this automatically, along with any other features/functionalities you might want on it.

Comment: @ManavM I am bit new to react, Is it possible to share a snippet?

Comment: Well take your current code, add url as a prop to it, switch `'api/query/fetch'` with `this.props.url` and then use the `Dashboard` component like `<Dashboard url={'api/query/fetch'} />` So that you will have all of this code that you have written reused for each table.